# MVC, Java Design Pratices, and Flaws of java.util.Observable and java.util.Observer

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc

I am planning learning Model-View-Controller (MVC) development using Java. While reading I came across a [post](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/mvc/mvcgui.html) which mentions **java.util.Observer** and **java.util.Observable** for MVC development.

As I never heard of it before, upon more googling I came across this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380676/is-java-util-observable-used-anywhere), which discusses some design flaw with the above-mentioned classes.

My question now has three parts

1. Are these classes still used in Industry for MVC development (except Eclipse as mentioned in the SO post)?
2. What are the flaws with these classes and why/why not should one use them?
3. Are there some ways MVC projects are developed in industry? (would be
   nice if you can answer this in general terms, NOT looking for
   answers like **SPRING** :P ) **[edit: both for desktop and web applications]**

Comment: About the third question, you mean only MVC for desktop applications or also for web applications?

Comment: @vitalik I did not think of that variation when writing, but now as you mentioned it, it would be nice to know what is the industry-standard for both :). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer only about web development.

Apart from the rare cases when you use [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/), you usually don't have Java code running on the client machine. This implies that you can't implement the Observer interface. Usually your view is HTML and javascript.

A recent trend in web development is using MVC implementations written in Javascript, like [JavascriptMVC](http://www.javascriptmvc.com/), [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), and many others. This goes even more far away from those interfaces.

Also recently, Google proposed the usage of the [Model-View-Presenter pattern](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture), that is a modification of the MVC.